# PL/Sql- Update multiple rows by subtracting the existing value in the column by one

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I get this recordset from a select:

```
DOCID      PAGENUM      
--------- ---------- 
  6000249          4          
  6000249          2          
  6000249          3
```

And now, I'd like to know if is it possible to update the pagenum column by subtracting it by one in a single expression.

Comment: `update table set pagenum = pagenum - 1;`

Comment: Are you trying to update the source table? Are you trying to change the SELECT statement's  results before they're passed to a client? What ***precisely*** are you trying to do? The best approach is always to make a reproducible example; [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wish to update the table itself, a simple update statement would suffice.

```
update table set pagenum = pagenum + 1;
```

If however since you mention "recordset" and "PL/SQL" you have pulled this data into a PL/SQL nested table, varray or associative array (all in-memory structures), you have to loop to modify each record. There isn't a single expression that will change it for you akin to javascript's map array method. So, if you have a nested table loaded via "bulk collect into" you can operate on it iteratively in this way:

```
begin

  -- load recordset from query, then...

  for i in recordset.first .. recordset.last
  loop
    recordset(i).pagenum := recordset(i).pagenum + 1;
  end loop;
end;
```

Comment: The OP wants to change the value "by subtracting it by one".